# How many positive integral solutions does $a+b+c+d+e=20$ have, if $a<b<c<d<e$?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Let $a<b<c<d<e$ be positive integers such that $a+b+c+d+e=20$, then the number of such distinct arrangement possible are __? Please also provide the general solution for every sum of numbers

I have tried this using counting form arranging $1,2,3,4,10$ etc, got the answer $7$ but want to find a general solution of instead of $20 ,100$ is said , then we can't count it manually?

Comment: This is not a forum where people will do your homework for you, sorry.

Comment: I am not here for getting for homework solution I am here for getting solutions for my competitive exams which will decide my future so pls take it seriously and don't ever comment this cause none of the school provide this level of ques and also rather focusing on other things please try to help students

Comment: @SarveshKanth People would love to help you have a bright future. However, the way MSE works is - you have a question, you make an honest attempt to solve it but get stuck. So you come here, include the details of your attempt and ask how to proceed. Or maybe if there's a mistake or a better solution.

Comment: In the absence of those details and context, your question will often be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have edited the question, can you please answer me !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Number of integer solutions if $x_1\leq x_2\leq x_3\leq \cdots\leq x_r\leq k$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76684/number-of-integer-solutions-if-x-1-leq-x-2-leq-x-3-leq-cdots-leq-x-r-leq-k)

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Also, have you tried searching the site?  This https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2754764/number-of-integer-solutions-to-linear-equation-with-restrictions
Or here
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868785/how-many-positive-integer-solutions-are-there-to-the-equality-x-1x-2-x-r?rq=1

Comment: $r+s+t+u+v+w=20$, $r=a,s=b-a,t=c-b,u=d-c,v=e-d,w=20-e$.

Comment: [1] Is your test multichoice ? [2] Are you allowed a laptop ? [3] If not, what calculators are you allowed to use ?

Comment: This particular ques has a single numerical answer . The test is online but no calculators are allowed

Comment: @SarveshKanth You're trying to cheat in an exam and saying so publicly. If I were you, I would delete this question. Good luck in your exams.

Comment: @WildFeather: OP has already provided the answer, is looking for a better *manual* method than brute force for larger problems, I don't know any.

Comment: @trueblueanil I really hope this question doesn't get closed. It's a good one.

Comment: @Haris: I don't think it'll be closed now !

Answer (score 1):

**Before we dive in**

It's a good question and the answer you've got $(7)$ is correct as well.

Now, assuming you have to solve this question with high school math only (and no calculators/computers allowed), I don't think there's a simple solution that can be generalized. You may still want to explore the links to a couple of other SE questions mentioned in the comments.

That said, here's how I would approach this problem. I hope it would be of some value to you and some others.

**Solution**

The solutions have to be positive integers and then we have the condition that no two of them should be equal.

What we can do is assign $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$,and $5$ to the variables to begin with. So for example, $a = 1$, and $d = 4$.

These are minimum values the variables have to take in order to be positive integers and strictly increasing.

Also, at this stage their sum is already $15$. So our new adjusted equation becomes

$$a' + b' + c' + d' + e' = 5$$

The benefit of what we just did is that we have an equation of the form$^{[1]}$

$$x_1 + x_2 \, + \, ... \, + \, x_n = n$$

where $x_i$ is a non-negative integer and $x_{i+1} \le x_i$ (one variable is greater than or equal to that preceding it).

We need to find the number of solutions to this equation.

While I don't have a simple formula/method to get an answer, as long as $n$ is small, as it is in our case here ($5$), we can find the number of solutions by counting - as you did. Here's how we can count in a systematic way, so we are less likely to make a mistake.

We start by giving assigning the maximum value to the last variable, and then bring it down by $1$ at a time.

So, for $n = 5$

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c} 
 x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_4 & x_5\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 5\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 4\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 3\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 3\\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2\\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 2\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 
\end{array}$$

**Another similar problem**

If you think this kind of approach has no real advantage over just randomly trying to find five distinct non-integral values that add to $20$, try the following question (I just made it up).

Let $x_1 + x_2 \, + \, ... \, + \, x_6 = 42$. Find the number of solutions to this equation, such that

1. $x_i$ is a positive integer
2. $x_{i+1} - x_i >1$

Please feel free to comment and make suggestions that can help improve/correct this answer.

---

**Footnotes**

$^{[1]}$ I don't think it's a coincidence that number of variable matches the sum we are getting at this stage. And so a question with $4$ variable could look something like this.

Let a<b<c<d be positive integers such that a+b+c+d=14, then the number of such distinct arrangement possible are __?

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Haris' answer, we start with $(a,b,c,d,e)=(1,2,3,4,5)$. Therefore, the sum of the five numbers is $15$. Now we find the solutions by following a sequence of steps, the possible steps are:

- Add $1$ to all five numbers
- Add $1$ to $b,c,d,e$
- Add $1$ to $c,d,e$
- Add $1$ to $d,e$
- Add $1$ to $e$

Each step can be performed multiple times and the order of the steps does not matter. These steps increase the sum of the five numbers while preserving $a<b<c<d<e$. Let $x_{i}$ be the number of times the step $i$ appear in the sequence,  now we need to find the number of integer solutions to

$$
5x_{1}+4x_{2}+3x_{3}+2x_{4}+x_{5}=5
$$

which I find easier to solve than the original counting problems, and the solution is $7$.